# Postgresql using Dapper to force "ANY(VALUES(), ()...)" for a list

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

I have a query simply like this:

```
SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY(ARRAY['key1', 'key2', ...])
```

According to the article [100x faster Postgres performance by changing 1 line](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/), using `VALUES` instead of `ARRAY` can improve the performance. I've also tried the solution and the query has better performance:

```
SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY(VALUES('key1'), ('key2'), ...)
```

But I am passing the `keyList` via Dapper:

```
SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY(@keyList)
```

and it translete the query with array:

```
SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY($1)
```

My question is how can I force Dapper to use the query with `VALUES`?

And this is the implementation roughly:

```
var query = @"SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY(@keyList)";

var keyList = new[] { "key1", "key2", ... };
List<int> list;
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    list = await connection.QueryAsync<int>(query, new {keyList});
}
```

Comment: how do you pass with dapper? can you add the relevant part of the code?

Comment: i added the implementation @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported the same way in various databases and Dapper doesn't know which DBMS you are using, so I don't think you can get Dapper to do it. I would just build it myself like:

```cs
var keyList = new[] { "key1", "key2", ... };
var keyValues = String.Join(",",keyList.Select(x=>$"('{x}')"));
var query = $@"SELECT restaurant_id as Id FROM restaurants WHERE unique_key = ANY(VALUES{keyValues})";

List<int> list;
using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    list = await connection.QueryAsync<int>(query);
}
```

You should of course take precautions if `keyList` is user input and protect against SQL Injection.